# ABC is a triangle. What is the value of tan^3 A + tan^3 B + tan^3 C in terms of p & q?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

p = sin A . sin B . sin C

q = cos A . cos B . cos C

---

**My approach so far**

since ABC is a triangle

then, : tan A + tan B + tan C = tan A tan B tan C

and further using : tan A tan B + tan B tan C + tan C tan A = 1 + sec A sec B sec C

Then cubing both sides , but thats too long possibly wont yield an answer .

How do I simplify the cubic expression .

Comment: To be corrected in title $ \tan$^B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc \equiv (a+b+c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 -(ab + bc + ca))$

Comment: Yup , just arrived it myself .

Comment: How do you get $\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A$ in terms of $p,q$?

Comment: @cr001 Since A + B + C = pi => tan ( A + B + C ) = 0 ; Tan ( A + B + C ) = ( tan A + tan B + tan C - tan A - tan B - tan C ) / ( 1 - tanA tan B - Tan B tan C - tan C tan A ) = 0 => tan A + tan B + tan C = tan A tan B tan C

Comment: $\tan A + \tan B +\ tan C = \tan A \tan B \tan C$ only implies ${1\over \tan A\tan B}+{1\over \tan B\tan C}+{1\over \tan C\tan A}=1$ but in order to use the formula in this answer, we must know the value of $\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A$ (i.e $ab+bc+ca$). The second bracket can be written as $(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)$ and we know $a+b+c={p\over q}$ but we still don't know $ab+bc+ca$.

Comment: A better representation is  a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = ( a + b + c ) ^ 3 - 3 [ ( a + b + c ) ( ab + bc + ca ) - abc )

Comment: @cr001 tan A tan B + tan B tan C + tan C tan A = 1 + sec A sec B sec C = 1 + 1 / q , where q is the product of angle cosines of triangles.

Comment: how is that any better? You still don't know the value of the sum of the pairwise products

Comment: @Ricky Thanks, that formula seems to be true. Very clever to come up with that.

Comment: @cr001 These formulas work only for the fact that A + B + C = pi , I have also derived formulas as this for ( A + B + C ) = odd multiple or even multiple of pi , then they also differ for n. ( pi ) where n = ( 1 , 5 , 9 .. ) which is in this case . I call this 1st kind odd . for 2nd kind odd ( 3 , 7 , 11 .. ) for instance sin A + sin B + sin C = -4 cos A/2 cos B/2 cos C/2 ...but fortunately tangent properties are same no matter of n(pi) is odd , even , 1st kind or 2nd kind ..

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for your expression simplification. You can use multinomial theorem for $(a+b+c)^3$ jts $\sum n!.\frac{a^{n_1}.b^{n_2}c^{n_3}}{n_1!.n_2!.n_3!}$.and the condition is $n_1+n_2+n_3=n$  Can you get it from there. Hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Use

$$ (a + b + c)^3 \equiv  a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3 (a+b)(b+c)(c+a) $$

along with other relations.